# Stopping and resuming VLC

Tags: linux, vlc

I am trying to play some music in Linux (specifically in the Rapsberry Pi) using VLC. I am playing both streams and local songs. In the streams, to pause and resume the stream, simply kill and re-call the command, but in the song, I want to kill the command and then start playing in the same second I was.

I know how to play form a certain second (`vlc --start-time SECOND ...`) but, how to know in which second is the program playing to then resume?

**Or in a simpler way, how to pause and resume the reproduction of a song in VLC?**

Answer (score 0):

So you want to control VLC on your terminal while it's playing - did I get you right?

VLC has many interfaces available (https://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces/), one is to interact on the terminal:

```
vlc --intf rc yourSong.mp3
```

Type `help` at the command prompt to get the commands available: `pause` and `play` should be what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to be able the pause and play things from the linux shell, not vlc's, since I am calling the commands form a python subprocess. How can I do so?

Comment: I see two possibilities: pipe the commands to vlc or open a network connection as in https://wiki.videolan.org/Console/. Anyway, you didn't provide code, so it's a bit difficult to give specific help.

Comment: I didn't provide any code because the code I had was not related with vlc. I was going to write that part after I knew how to focus it, since depending on how I should do it, I would organise my code in a way, etcetera

Comment: Right now I have been just trying to pipe the commands into the vlc directly with a sub process but I could not make it work yet and it seems very complicated. I thought it could have been easier.

Comment: By the way I'm using Python for that